# Recursively list concents of Oracle's DBA_DEPENDENCIES view

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, recursive-query

I would like a list of dependent tables (ultimately) of a given view.

For example:

```
SELECT NAME, TYPE, REFERENCED_NAME, REFERENCED_TYPE
FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE OWNER='FOO'
AND NAME='VIEW_O1'
```

The results:

```
VIEW_O1 VIEW    TABLE_01    TABLE
VIEW_O1 VIEW    TABLE_02    TABLE
VIEW_O1 VIEW    TABLE_03    TABLE
VIEW_O1 VIEW    VIEW_02     VIEW
VIEW_O1 VIEW    VIEW_03     VIEW
```

I would like it to resemble:

```
VIEW_O1 VIEW    TABLE_01    TABLE
VIEW_O1 VIEW    TABLE_02    TABLE
VIEW_O1 VIEW    TABLE_03    TABLE
VIEW_O1 VIEW    VIEW_02     VIEW
VIEW_O1 VIEW    VIEW_03     VIEW
VIEW_O2 VIEW    TABLE_03    TABLE
VIEW_O2 VIEW    TABLE_04    TABLE
VIEW_O3 VIEW    TABLE_05    TABLE
VIEW_O3 VIEW    VIEW_04     VIEW
VIEW_O4 VIEW    TABLE_06    TABLE
VIEW_O4 VIEW    TABLE_07    TABLE
VIEW_O4 VIEW    TABLE_08    TABLE
```

I suppose that I should also have a column that lists the starting point, so I can keep the ancestry in a group.

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT NAME, TYPE, REFERENCED_NAME, REFERENCED_TYPE
FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE OWNER='FOO'
AND NAME='VIEW_01'
CONNECT BY PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME=NAME
```

but I get an error that reads 'ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data'.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to specify the NOCYCLE keyword after your CONNECT BY:

i.e.

```
SELECT NAME, 
       TYPE, 
       REFERENCED_NAME, 
       REFERENCED_TYPE 
  FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES 
 WHERE OWNER='FOO' 
   AND NAME='VIEW_01' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
  PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME = NAME;
```

There is more info on NOCYCLE and the "CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE" keywords here:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_connect_by_loop.htm

and here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm

Hope it helps...

EDIT: After comments, you have missed the START WITH clause.

```
SELECT NAME, 
       TYPE, 
       REFERENCED_NAME, 
       REFERENCED_TYPE 
  FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES 
 WHERE OWNER='FOO' 
 START WITH NAME='VIEW_01' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
  PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME = NAME;
```

BTW, keeping the OWNER='FOO' where clause limits any dependencies returned to just FOO's object so you may possibly miss dependencies from other schemas.

Edit 2:
The primary key of a table of view is owner, name thus the select should start with both and connect by both. You can use where to filter out desired results.

```
SELECT OWNER, NAME, TYPE,  
   REFERENCED_OWNER,
   REFERENCED_NAME, 
   REFERENCED_TYPE 
FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES 
-- where referenced_type='TABLE'
START WITH owner = 'FOO' AND NAME='VIEW_01' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
   PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME = NAME
   AND PRIOR REFERENCED_OWNER = OWNER;
```

Comment: I tried this query.  Syntactically, it is correct, but the query never completes.  Is there another option?

Comment: Craig, you need to specify the START WITH clause telling the query where to start it's hierarchy. In your WHERE clause change the "AND NAME='VIEW_01'" to a START WITH clause.

Comment: OK, the STARTS WITH clause eliminated that problem.  Unfortunately, each row is now repeated twice.  I added SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (NAME,'/') to the SELECT clause.  Each record includes a path of /VIEW_01/VIEW_01/[NAME] in addition to a row with a path of /VIEW_01/[NAME].  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not in front of my test box at the moment but if you have a problem with duplicate rows you can filter them with the DISTINCT keyword. i.e. SELECT DISTINCT NAME, TYPE, REFERENCED_NAME...

Comment: I considered that, but I would lose the PATH part of the query.  Ideally, I'd eliminate the odd behavior.

Comment: If the path is different then the results aren't duplicates. What are the differences in the PATH values? Is the query finding synonyms etc.? It might be that you need to filter out the duplicates in a subquery before then using the hierarchical query to sort what's left.

Answer (score 0):

as Ollie said,
This is as the same:
This query resolves all deps starting with **MYPROC** as root of the tree.

```
SELECT A.NAME,
   A.TYPE,
   A.REFERENCED_OWNER,
   A.REFERENCED_NAME,
   A.REFERENCED_TYPE,
   A.REFERENCED_LINK_NAME,
   A.SCHEMAID  FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES A
 CONNECT BY PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME = A.NAME
 START WITH A.NAME = 'MYPROC'ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```