# Listing of all view / MV / table dependencies for an object

Tags: oracle, dependencies

I need to be able to produce a list of all views, packages, etc. and everything that they are dependent on - e.g. if procedure P1 uses views V1 and V2, and V2 uses V3, which uses table T1, and then view V12 also references V2, I want this list:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | V1 |
| P1 | V2 |
| P1 | V3 |
| P1 | T1 |
| V12 | V2 |
| V12 | V3 |
| V12 | T1 |

Using a solution mentioned [here][1],

[1]: [Recursively list concents of Oracle's DBA_DEPENDENCIES view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797922/recursively-list-concents-of-oracles-dba-dependencies-view), I'm almost there. HOWEVER, there is still one significant issue.

In an actual scenario, a MATERIALIZED VIEW has a table of the same name. Looking at the dependencies in TOAD, the outermost view just goes down to that view (and shows it as a table). Looking from the table level, TOAD only goes up as far as that same MV (and shows it as an MV). So there's a disconnect, apparently due to the MV and table having the same name. I tried removing the "and prior d.referenced_type = d.type" clause from the CONNECT BY but the only thing that did was make the query so it never completed.

A simplistic set of views etc. and expected results, are below:

```
create table t1 (field1 int);
insert into t1 values (1);
create or replace view v1 as (select field1 as levelno from t1);
create or replace view v2 as (select levelno + 1 as levelno from v1);
create materialized view v3 build immediate refresh force as (select levelno + 1 as levelno from v2);
select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'V3'; -- shows both table and MV named V3
create or replace view v4 as (select levelno + 1 as levelno from v3);
create or replace view v5 as (select levelno + 1 as levelno from v4);
with dependencies as (
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT 
d.owner as parent_owner, d.name AS parent_name, d.type as parent_type,  
d.referenced_owner as child_owner, d.referenced_name AS child_name, d.referenced_type as child_type, 
REFERENCED_LINK_NAME child_link, 
LEVEL DEPENDENCY_LEVEL,
level-1 pathlength,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(type||'.'||name, '->') Path, 
CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE  is_cycle
FROM dba_dependencies d
where d.owner = user
START WITH d.type in ( 'PROCEDURE','PACKAGE','VIEW','MATERIALIZED VIEW','FUNCTION')
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR d.referenced_name = d.name
and prior d.referenced_owner = d.owner
and prior d.referenced_type = d.type
), 
ordered_dependencies as (
select  
parent_type, parent_owner, parent_name,  
child_type, child_owner, child_name, child_Link,
row_number () over (
partition by parent_type, parent_owner, parent_name, child_type, child_owner, child_name order by dependency_level desc
) rn,
dependency_level, pathlength, path
from dependencies d 
)
select 
regexp_substr(substr(path,3),'[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+',1,1) as TOP_LVL_type, 
regexp_substr(substr(path,3),'[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+',1,2) as top_lvl_name ,
child_type, child_name, rn, path,
parent_type, parent_name
from ordered_dependencies 
where rn = 1 
order by child_name, parent_name, rn
;
 
Expected results: 

|TOP LVL TYPE|TOP LVL NAME|CHILD TYPE|CHILD NAME|RN|PATH|PARENT TYPE|PARENT NAME|
|:----:|:----:|:---:|:---:|:--:|:----:|:----:|:-----:|
|VIEW|V5|TABLE|T1|1|->VIEW.V5->VIEW.V4->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3->VIEW.V2->VIEW.V1|VIEW|V1|
|VIEW|V5|VIEW|V1|1|->VIEW.V5->VIEW.V4->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3->VIEW.V2|VIEW|V2|
|VIEW|V5|VIEW|V2|1|->VIEW.V5->VIEW.V4->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3|VIEW|V3|
|VIEW|V5|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|1|->VIEW.V5->VIEW.V4|VIEW|V4|
|VIEW|V5|VIEW|V4|1|->VIEW.V5|VIEW|V5|

Actual results:

|TOP LVL TYPE|TOP LVL NAME|CHILD TYPE|CHILD NAME|RN|PATH|PARENT TYPE|PARENT NAME|
|----|----|---|---|--|----|----|-----|
|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|TABLE|T1|1|->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3->VIEW.V2->VIEW.V1|VIEW|V1|
|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|TABLE|T1|1|->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|
|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|VIEW|V1|1|->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3->VIEW.V2|VIEW|V2|
|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|VIEW|V1|1|->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|
|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|VIEW|V2|1|->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|
|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|TABLE|V3|1|->MATERIALIZED VIEW.V3|MATERIALIZED VIEW|V3|
|VIEW|V5|TABLE|V3|1|->VIEW.V5->VIEW.V4|VIEW|V4|
|VIEW|V5|VIEW|V4|1|->VIEW.V5|VIEW|V5|

Note that from V5, the lowest level it goes down to is the TABLE named V3. 
Going up from table T1, the highest level it goes up to is the MATERIALIZED VIEW V3. And it shows MV V3 as the parent of TABLE V3. 

This is consistent with how TOAD displays the dependencies as well. Basically I think the DBA_DEPENDENCIES view falls down, badly, when there's an MV in the equation.
```

Comment: It could be interesting problems, but please split in two questions where you demonstrate your actual problem (with actual data and wrong and expected result).

Comment: Reworked question with an example showing where the breakdown is. I couldn't get the expected / actual results to show as a table because the website insisted I was trying to show code!